# No me crea la tabla de mi plugin en wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Estoy creando un plugin para un formulario personalizado en wordpress, pero cuando lo activo, no me crea la tabla en la base de datos, decir que soy nuevo programando en wordpress y estoy muy verde.

```
function InscripSolabria_init()
{
    global $wpdb; // Este objeto global nos permite trabajar con la BD de WP
    // Crea la tabla si no existe
    $tabla_inscritos = $wpdb->prefix . 'inscritos';
    $tabla_actividades = $wpdb->prefix . 'actividades';
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    $query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tabla_inscritos (
        id_inscritos INT(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        nombre varchar(40) NOT NULL,
        correo varchar(100) NOT NULL,
        telefono varchar(40) NOT NULL,
        FK_id_actividades INT(4) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY
        )
         $charset_collate;";

         $query2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tabla_actividades(
            id_actividades INT(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            actividades varchar(100) NOT NULL,
            imagen varchar(100) NULL,
            horarios varchar(500)NULL
            REFERENCES(id_actividades) FOREIGN KEY inscritos(FK_id_actividades)
        )$charset_collate;";
    // La función dbDelta que nos permite crear tablas de manera segura se
    // define en el fichero upgrade.php que se incluye a continuación
    include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';
    dbDelta($query,$query2);
}
```

Comment: ¿Seguro que el plugin está funcionando? ¿Seguro que tu código entra en `InscripSolabria_init()`? Convendría que revises el log de errores para tener detalles específicos sobre los posibles fallos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que expones y la forma en que trabaja la función, te debe estar creando la tabla `inscritos`, pero no la de `actividades`, porque no estás proporcionando los parámetros correctamente para [dbDelta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/dbdelta/):

- Primer parámetro: Cadena con una o más consultas, separadas por `;` o arreglo con una o más consultas como cadena
- Segundo parámetro: Verdadero (por defecto) para ejecutar o falso para no ejecutar

Entonces, si la función internamente trabaja con arreglos, creo que lo más adecuado es enviar tus consultas dentro de un arreglo, encerrando entre corchetes:

```
dbDelta([$query, $query2]);
```

Adicionalmente, creo que tienes un error al crear la segunda tabla:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tabla_actividades(
        id_actividades INT(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        actividades varchar(100) NOT NULL,
        imagen varchar(100) NULL,
        horarios varchar(500)NULL  -- Falta una coma
        REFERENCES(id_actividades) FOREIGN KEY inscritos(FK_id_actividades)
    )$charset_collate;
```

Te recomiendo primero probar las consultas en PhpMyAdmin para saber que funcionan o aplicar las correcciones necesarias. Después ya las integras en el *plugin*.

Answer (score 0):

El error se basa en que no estás usando los backsticks para identificar tablas o columnas. La solución propuesta es la siguiente

```
function InscripSolabria_init()
{
    global $wpdb; // Este objeto global nos permite trabajar con la BD de WP
    // Crea la tabla si no existe
    $tabla_inscritos = $wpdb->prefix . 'inscritos';
    $tabla_actividades = $wpdb->prefix . 'actividades';
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    $query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tabla_inscritos (
        `id_inscritos` INT(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        `nombre` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
        correo varchar(100) NOT NULL,
        `telefono` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
        `FK_id_actividades` INT(4) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY
        )
         $charset_collate;";

         $query2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tabla_actividades(
            `id_actividades` INT(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            `actividades` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
            `imagen` varchar(100) NULL,
            `horarios` varchar(500)NULL, //Faltaba una coma aquí
            REFERENCES(`id_actividades`) FOREIGN KEY inscritos(`FK_id_actividades`)
        )$charset_collate;";
    // La función dbDelta que nos permite crear tablas de manera segura se
    // define en el fichero upgrade.php que se incluye a continuación
    include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';
    dbDelta($query,$query2);
}
```